# Angular 2 - Inject authorization token before each Http request

Tags: angular, rxjs, keycloak

I need to check that my token is not expired before I send every HTTP request. I'm trying to make injection using Http Interceptor like this:

```
class HttpInterceptor extends Http {

  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, private _router: Router) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    const keycloak$: Observable = KeycloakService.updateToken();

    return keycloak$.map((options) => {
      return super.get(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
    });
    // -> Observable<Observable<Response>>
  }

  getRequestOptionArgs(options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : RequestOptionsArgs {
    if (options == null) {
        options = new RequestOptions();
    }
    if (options.headers == null) {
        options.headers = new Headers();
    }
    options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return options;
  }
}
```

How I can implement Observable dependency. `KeycloakService.updateToken()` returns another `Observable`, so I need to wait for response and then add Authorization header. I will be grateful for any tips.

Comment: How is your `KeycloakService.updateToken()` returning an Observable? The code I got from Keycloak's website returns a Promise. Could you point me to where I can find the Observable version of the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `switchMap` to wait for the observable returned by `super.get()` to resolve before emitting the response

Replace

```
return keycloak$.map((options) => {
  return super.get(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
});
```

With

```
return keycloak$.switchMap(
    options => super.get(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options))
);
```

[Examples](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35#switchmap)

I would also change:

```
if (options == null) {
    options = new RequestOptions();
}
if (options.headers == null) {
    options.headers = new Headers();
}
```

With:

```
if(!options) options = new RequestOptions();
if(!options.headers) options.headers = new Headers();
```

In order to catch `undefined` as well as `null` options

Comment: for me the same method is not working. can you please help me understand a bit more. i posted a question with details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872897/angular-getting-authorization-token-asynchronously-before-http-calls